# Buttons not working on subsequent tabs to redraw chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to display multiple charts, each on a different tab. I have added some buttons to the bottom of the chart to turn on and off all the series, and to turn on and off groupings of the series. These buttons work on the first tab, but not on subsequent tabs. Each tab goes to a different page based on the stat group (Chart1, Chart2, Chart3):

```
<a href="path_to_file/ajax.<?php echo $statGroup; ?>.php?host=<?php echo $statGroup; ?>&from=<?php echo $from; ?>&through=<?php echo $through; ?>"><?php echo $statGroup; ?></a>
```

The code for the highchart is different on each page that is called, but the buttons only work on the first tab. The data is displaying correctly for each tab. Here is the code I'm using, where it says "StatGroup1" is changed to StatGroup2 and so on for each tab:

```
$from = isset($var_from) ? $var_from : strtotime('-36 hours');
$through = isset($var_through) ? $var_through : time();
//print_r(getcwd());

$stats = new cimsSonusEMS($through, $from);

$series = array();
foreach ($stats->get_cpu($statGroup) as $slot => $util) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ($util as $time => $stat) {
        $time *= 1000;
        $data[] = "[$time, $stat]";
    }

    $data_string = implode(',', $data);
    $series[] = "{ name: 'Slot $slot', type: 'spline', data: [$data_string]}";
}

?>

<div id="graph-StatGroup1"></div>
<div id="onOffButtons">
    <button id="allOn"> All Cards On </button>
    <button id="allOff"> All Cards Off </button>
    <button id="MNSoff" value="MNS Off"> MNS On/Off </button>
    <button id="PNSoff" value="PNS Off"> PNS On/Off </button>
    <button id="SPSoff" value="SPS Off"> SPS On/Off </button>
    <button id="CNSoff" value="CNS Off"> CNS On/Off </button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    chartStatGroup1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'graph-StatGroup1',
            zoomType: 'x',
            width: 900,
            height: 400
        },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        title: { text: 'CPU Utilization by Card' },
        legend: { itemWidth: 120 },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            maxZoom: 1000 * 3600 * 6,
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e<br />%H:%M', this.value);
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            formatter: function() {
                var tip = Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %B %e, %l:%M %P', this.x);
                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                    tip += '<br /><span style="color: ' + point.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span>: ' + point.y + '%';
                });

                return tip;
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: { text: null },
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            radius: 5
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [ <?php echo implode(',', $series); ?> ]
    });
    $("#allOn").click(function(){
        var series = chartStatGroup1.series;

        for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
            series[i].setVisible(true, false);
        }
        chartStatGroup1.redraw();
        alert("All On");
        MNSoff.value = "MNS Off";
        PNSoff.value = "PNS Off";
        SPSoff.value = "SPS Off";
        CNSoff.value = "CNS Off";
    });
    $("#allOff").click(function() {
        var series = chartStatGroup1.series;

        for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
            series[i].setVisible(false, false);
        }
        chartStatGroup1.redraw();
        alert("All Off");
        MNSoff.value = "MNS On";
        PNSoff.value = "PNS On";
        SPSoff.value = "SPS On";
        CNSoff.value = "CNS On";
    });
    $("#MNSoff").click(function() {
        var series = chartStatGroup1.series;

        if (this.value == "MNS Off") {
            series[0].setVisible(false, false);
            series[1].setVisible(false, false);

            chartStatGroup1.redraw();
            alert("MNS off");
        this.value = "MNS On";
    } else {
        series[0].setVisible(true, false);
        series[1].setVisible(true, false);

        chartStatGroup1.redraw();
        alert("MNS on");
        this.value = "MNS Off";
    }
});
$("#PNSoff").click(function() {
    var series = chartStatGroup1.series;

    if (this.value == "PNS Off") {
        series[2].setVisible(false, false);
        series[3].setVisible(false, false);
        series[4].setVisible(false, false);

        chartStatGroup1.redraw();
        alert("PNS off");
        this.value = "PNS On";
    } else {
        series[2].setVisible(true, false);
        series[3].setVisible(true, false);
        series[4].setVisible(true, false);

        chartStatGroup1.redraw();
        alert("PNS on");
        this.value = "PNS Off";
    }
});
$("#SPSoff").click(function() {
    var series = chartStatGroup1.series;

    if (this.value == "SPS Off") {
        series[5].setVisible(false, false);
        series[6].setVisible(false, false);

        chartStatGroup1.redraw();
        alert("SPS off");
        this.value = "SPS On";
    } else {
        series[5].setVisible(true, false);
        series[6].setVisible(true, false);

        chartStatGroup1.redraw();
        alert("SPS on");
        this.value = "SPS Off";
    }
});
$("#CNSoff").click(function() {
    var series = chartStatGroup1.series;

    if (this.value == "CNS Off") {
        series[7].setVisible(false, false);
        series[8].setVisible(false, false);
        series[9].setVisible(false, false);
        series[10].setVisible(false, false);
        series[11].setVisible(false, false);
        series[12].setVisible(false, false);
        series[13].setVisible(false, false);

        chartStatGroup1.redraw();
        alert("CNS off");
        this.value = "CNS On";
    } else {
        series[7].setVisible(true, false);
        series[8].setVisible(true, false);
        series[9].setVisible(true, false);
        series[10].setVisible(true, false);
        series[11].setVisible(true, false);
        series[12].setVisible(true, false);
        series[13].setVisible(true, false);

        chartStatGroup1.redraw();
        alert("CNS on");
        this.value = "CNS Off";
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I can't use Highstock, just Highcharts. Thanks.

UPDATE:

The code that worked is as follows:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function () {
        var series = chartCMHGSX2.series;

        for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
            series[i].setVisible(true, false);
        }
        chartCMHGSX2.redraw();
        alert("All On");
        MNSoff.value = "MNS Off";
        PNSoff.value = "PNS Off";
        SPSoff.value = "SPS Off";
        CNSoff.value = "CNS Off";
    }
}, '#allOn');
```

Thank you very much @popnoodles for your help!

Comment: It's going to be that you're using `$('#something').click()` instead of `$(document).on('click', '#something')` - I can't be bothered to post yet another answer explaining the difference. Someone will.

Comment: Thank you so very much. That solved my problem very nicely.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it does the job, so this question no longer shows as unanswered.

Comment: I'm sorry, at the time that I said thank you, you had not created the answer yet. I was working on research before I answered it myself. You did well, and I thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because highcharts is creating elements dynamically. When the JS is executed, only the elements that exist at that time know the instruction they are given.

Fortunately when you click something, unless it's explicitly told not to, that click bubbles all the way up to document.

So, what you do is bind the event to any ancestor that exists and won't be overwritten, the failsafe being `document`, and delegate the event to the element you want the interaction with, which may or may not exist at the time that JS is executed. As long as the ancestor exists, the instruction will be noted.

So, this `$('#something').click(function(){})` may work once, but `#something` is overwritten, its replacement doesn't know the instruction.

With this `$(document).on('click', '#something', function(){})` `document` does know the instruction, hears the click, and if `#something` is the target or an ancestor of the target, that instruction will be executed.